# What would be an algorithm to check if two people would meet as they traverse a graph using dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Imagine 2 people starting a two different starting points in a 2D matrix. They would also have separate end points when they traverse the matrix. Traversing from two points has a corresponding difficulty (weight). Using Djikstra's algorithm, we can determine what would be the best route to take for both person to reach their destination. Given that a person can only move to one node at a time and both persons move simultaneously, what would be a good algorithm to determine if they would bump to each other as they traverse the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform two Djikstra's searches from two initial vertices, you update `dist[]` and `prev[]` arrays (looking at [Wiki pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode))

Add additional array `steps[]` (for distance in number of edges), and when you modify  `prev[v] ← u`, also make `steps[v] = steps[u] + 1`

When you read shortest path by reverse iterations, compare if vertices of intersection of two paths contain the same value in `steps`

For example, you found that paths intersect in vertices 3 and 7. But `A_steps[3] = 3, B_steps[3] = 2` - so persons walk through this cell in differen moments. And if `A_steps[7] = 6, B_steps[7] = 6` means that persons do meet in this node at the sixth step.

Comment: Thanks. To add i think if A_steps[3] = 3 && A_steps[4] = 4  && B_steps[3] = 4 && B_steps = 3 also means that the two persons bumped to each other.